# alternating href store url

Tags: url, slider

in our online shop we use a fullsize slider.
I would like to provide 3 links in the same slider using the same image. So that one time a customer clicks on the slider is referred to categorie a and the next customer to categorie b. So I'm searching for an alternating href store url.

```
a href="{{store url='onlineshop/categorie-a.html''}}"
a href="{{store url='onlineshop/categorie-b.html''}}"
a href="{{store url='onlineshop/categorie-c.html''}}"
```

First of all: Is that possible? What do I have to do so that it is alternating?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple link like:

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" onclick ="window.open('http://www.google.com'); window.open('http://www.yahoo.com' );">Click Here </a>
```